# docker - dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.1.254:53: no such host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Trying to run a docker image with docker inside it, however, it fails with this error:

```
docker: error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/create": dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.1.254:53: no such host.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker:24.0.6-dind

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache python3

COPY build.sh ./build.sh

RUN chmod +x /build.sh

VOLUME ["/var/run/docker.sock"]
```

build.sh is a script that will create a docker container for the build.

Any idea?

Tried changing nameserver to 8.8.8.8 on my local `etc/resolv.conf`. Did not fix.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Do you really need to directly manage containers from your program, or can you interact with preëxisting containers over a network connection or job queue?  Since a container only runs one process, trying to add your application into a Docker-in-Docker image won't work – the container will run your application or the DinD daemon, but not both.